# Correctness of the proof that $ |f(c+h)-f(c)| ≤ w(|h|)$ implies $f$ is continuous at $c$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Question: Let $\omega: [0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be continuous at $x = 0$ with $\omega(0) = 0$.
>
> Suppose for some point c $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ the function $f$: $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow $ $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies
> $$ |f(c+h)-f(c)| ≤ w(|h|)$$
> for every $h \in \mathbb{R}$ Show that $f$ is continuous at $c$.
>
> [image]

What I have attempted:

$\omega$ is continuous at $x =0$, with $w(0) = 0$. Therefore for all $ε > 0$ , there exists a $δ > 0$ s.t. if $x$ $\in$ $[0, ∞)$ and $|x - 0|$ $=$ $|x|$ $<$ $δ$, then $|\omega(x) - \omega(0)|$ $=$ $|\omega(x) - 0|$ = $|\omega(x)|$ $<$ $ε$ .

Note that as the co domain of $\omega$ is $[0,∞)$ $|\omega(x)| = \omega(x)$ for all $x \in [0, ∞)$. Note also that if $x \in ℝ$ then $|x| ∈ [0, ∞)$ (and so is in the domain of $\omega$).

Therefore if for some point $\omega ∈ ℝ$, $f:ℝ->ℝ$ satisfies $|f(c+h) - f(c)|$ <= $\omega(|h|) = |\omega(|h|)|$ for all $h ∈ ℝ$ , then we know that for all $ε > 0 $ there exists a $δ > 0$ s.t. if $||h|| = |h| < δ$, $|f(c+h) - f(c)|$ $< w(|h|) < ε $ (since $|h|$ $∈$ $[0, ∞)$.

It follows then that for all $h ∈ ℝ f(c+h) = f(c)$, since if this is not true $|f(c+h) - f(c)| > 0$ and we cannot take $ε = |f(c+h) - f(c)|$ (contradiction). And so for all $h ∈ ℝ f(c+h) = f(c)$, from which is follows that, for all $x ∈ ℝ$ , $f(x) = k$ for some $k ∈ ℝ$.

Hence for all $ε > 0$ there exists $δ > 0$ s.t. if $|x-c| < δ$, and $x ∈ ℝ$, $|f(x) - f(c)| = 0 < ε$. For example, $δ = 1$ works for all $x,c$.

Hence $f$ is continuous at $c$.

---

Is this proof correct? I'm worried that it's not what they were after, and if so is there a nicer proof?

Comment: This train derailed when you decided that $f(c+h)=f(c)$ for all $h$.  Up to then it looked promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part "if follows that for all $h \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(c+h) = f(c)$" is wrong. We only have that $f(c+h)$ and $f(c)$ are $\epsilon$-close whenever $|h| < \delta$. As a counterexample, consider $w(x) = f(x) = x$. Then it is not true that $f$ is constant but for every $h$ and $c$ we do have $|f(c+h) - f(c)| = |h| \leq w(|h|)$.

To show that $f$ is continuous at $c$ we have to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. Writing $x = c + h$, we see that this is equivalent to $|h| < \delta$ implies $|f(c+h) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. But, as you've noted, the fact that $w$ is continuous at $0$ gives us a $\delta$ such that $|h|< \delta$ implies $w(|h|) < \epsilon$. Hence for this $\delta$ we have that $|h| < \delta$ implies $|f(c+h)-f(c)| \leq w(|h|) < \epsilon$, as desired.